# PUPPETEER - Need to click element to get its updated innerText, I only get the unupdated one

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, puppeteer

I am getting crazy trying to scrape some data on a private platform. I have a list of events formatted as a table with nature of event, date, place, and field worker associated with the event. If the worker is alone, I have no trouble extracting its name. If however he is not alone and working in a team, that's where I can't get it done.

Here is a table showing the two cases:

| Event # | Worker |
| --- | --- |
| 39541 | SMITH Paul |
| 84751 | SMITH Paul (+1) |

And the HTML related to the table cell containing worker information on both lines.

First line:

```
<td class="pure-datatable-col-technician  pure-datatable-cell " id="yui_3_17_2_1_1671091653408_2904">
"SMITH Paul"
</td>
```

Second line:

```
<td class="pure-datatable-col-technician  pure-datatable-cell " id="yui_3_17_2_1_1671091653408_2781">
"SMITH Paul&nbsp;"
    <span class="teammates-loader" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1671091653408_2782">
        "("
        <a id="yui_3_17_2_1_1671091653408_2784">+1</a>
        ")"
    </span>
</td>
```

Notice there is no information about the other teammates in the html related to the second line.
However if I click on the span element, using `document.querySelectorAll("td[class='pure-datatable-col-technician  pure-datatable-cell '] > span")[0].click()`, the second line html changes to:

```
<td class="pure-datatable-col-technician  pure-datatable-cell " id="yui_3_17_2_1_1671091653408_3034">
    <span class="etech-technician-leader" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1671091653408_3082">
    "SMITH Paul"
    </span>
    ", BAKER Michael"
</td>
```

And the information related to other workers appears.

**My strategy consisted in clicking every worker element having the span child as soon as Puppeteer arrives on the target page, before scraping its elements.**

To compare retrieved worker data before and after the click, I basically did:

```
let pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {

    let baseWorkerData = [];
    let newWorkerData = [];
    let teamCells = document.querySelectorAll("td[class='pure-datatable-col-technician  pure-datatable-cell '] > span");

    for (var z = 0; z < teamCells.length; z++) {
        baseWorkerData.push(teamCells[z].parentElement.innerText);
        teamCells[z].click();
        newWorkerData.push(teamCells[z].parentElement.innerText);
    };

    let result = {"baseWorkerData": baseWorkerData, "newWorkerData": newWorkerData};

    return result;

});
```

The result:

```
{
  baseCell: [
    "SMITH Paul (+1)"
  ],
  newCell: [
    "SMITH Paul (+1)"
  ],
}
```

Nothing changes. I checked with `headless=false`, the elements are correctly clicked on. The additional worker information visually shows up on page and in html code. Yet I can't scrape it.

Comment: AFAIK .click() is asynchronous, so try `await teamCells[z].click()`

Comment: Well, if all the code inside evaluate is on the chromium side (jQuery), I can't use await there, can I?

Comment: I mean that the click is async. So you click on page, then read same data, 'cause click is not execute yet

Comment: Mmmh, passed the async parameter in the evaluate function: `page.evaluate(async() => {...});` in order to use await inside.

Same result unfortunately.

Comment: Browser `.click()` isn't async. This question is hard to follow. A runnable [mcve] would be great.

Comment: Sorry, I understand it is hard to follow but I don't see how I can provide a reprex.